# The type of the member [foo] of the declaring type [bar] is unknown GraphQL/Hot Chocolate (again)

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

Greetings and thanks in advance.  I am using .net6, GraphQL/Hot Chocolate/ChilliCream and have started my first test/GraphQL application.  I wish to use some of the non-standard GraphQL types, uint for example.  When the server starts up i get the very common:

"The type of the member XXX of the declaring type YYY is unknown"

I have included the scalar types package
I have tried:

```
    Services.AddTypes()
    Services.AddType<UnsignedIntType>()
    [GraphQLType(typeof(UnsignedIntType))] on the property
    Services.BindRuntimeType<uint, UnsignedIntType>()
```

my simple type looks like

```
   public class FooModel 
   { 
   public string ID { get; set; } 
   [GraphQLType(typeof(UnsignedIntType))] 
   public uint Dog { get; set; } 
   public Guid UID { get; set; } 
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   }
```

my services look like:

```
    builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer().AddType<UnsignedIntType> 
    ().AddQueryType<Query> 
    ().AddProjections().AddFiltering().AddSorting();
```

my query:

```
    public class Query
{

    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]   
    public IQueryable<TenantResponseModel> GetTenants([Service] 
    DarovaniContext context) //=> context.Tenants.AsQueryable();
    {
        return context.Tenants.Select(c => new TenantResponseModel()
        {
            Name = c.Name,
            ID = "cat", //.Id,
            UID = c.Uid,
            Dog = 0
        });
       }
    }
```

all the versions of all the GraphQL packages match (13.0.5)

Stumped at what i am doing incorrectly.  Any advice deeply appr.

steve

Comment: so the problem was filtering.  when i removed filtering it worked, adding it cause the exception.  the fix therefore was

`AddFiltering(x => x.AddDefaults().BindRuntimeType<uint,     UnsignedIntOperationFilterInputType>()).`


found at the bottom of this page
https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/fetching-data/filtering